# react-hook -form with SliderComponent input

Tags: reactjs, slider, react-hook-form

Im new to react and I am trying to use a SliderComponent in a react Hook form but I cant seem able to fully understand how Controller works.

Here is my SliderComponent using `react-input-slider`:

```
export default function SliderComponent(props) {
    
  const { axis, xmax, xmin, xstep, onChange } = props;;

  return (
    <div>
      <Slider
        axis={axis}
        x={value.x}
        xmax={xmax}
        xmin={xmin}
        xstep={xstep}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my form:

```
export default function BiometricForm() {
      const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
    
  return (
    <div className="registerForm_Container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onsubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="test"
          render={({ props: { x, axis, xmax, xmin, xstep } }) => (
            <SliderComponent
              axis={"x"}
              xmax={100}
              xmin={1}
              xstep={1}
              value={x}
              onChange={(e) => x.onChange(parseInt(e.target.value))}
            />
          )}
        />
        <button className="registerForm_Container_button" type="submit">
          Register
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think it might be something to do with useState and that I am not able to reach useState of component. I have read that maybe its not necessary , any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right, if you use RHF you don't need `useState` because RHF handles the form state for you. The important thing here is to pass an `onChange` handler to your `<SliderComponent />`, so that RHF can watch for value changes of your `<SliderComponent />` and update the form state. You should also provide a `defaultValue` for the field, if you don't want it to be undefined if the user doesn't change the slider before submitting.

Also without the `useState` inside `<SliderComponent />`, you can also omit the `<SliderComponent />` and just use `<Slider />`.

```
function BiometricForm() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="registerForm_Container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="test"
          defaultValue={50}
          render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
            <Slider
              axis={"x"}
              xmax={100}
              xmin={1}
              xstep={1}
              onChange={({ x }) => onChange(x)}
              x={value}
            />
          )}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Slider Controller (forked)]

Comment: You are absolutely right!! It works like a charm, I have tried to adjust my component so I can reuse it but some errors appear so I am going to follow your advice and use directly Slider . Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: If you want to reuse the slider, it's a great idea to create your own custom component. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-slider-controller-with-child-fc6jn) is another CodeSandbox recreating the use case of your question with an additional custom slider component. Maybe it will help finding your error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @knoefel, awesome help and codeSandbox is clear and super useful. Thanks again, you have made my day!